# How do I cache Images inside a DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a bunch of images in it

```
<div id="glueslide">
    <img src="tree.jpg" />
    <img src="cat.jpg" />
    <img src="dog.png" />
    <img src="horse.jpg" />
</div>
```

In my jQuery code I have used this code as

```
$(function () {
    var $img = $("#glueslide img");
    ...
    $img.filter(..);
    ..
    $img.eq(index).fadeOut(1000,function(){
    });
```

and so on..

As you can see, there is no caching. Now I want to introduce caching, cache all the images or preload them before using them.

How does my code change? What will I write instead of `var $img = $("#glueslide img");` so that the rest of my code doesn't change a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a much more complex problem than it looks. Writing it yourself is going to change your code significantly. If you are looking for a simple way of going about this the preserves most of what you wrote, I recommend the

#### [`waitForImages`](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)

plugin by [@alexdickson](https://twitter.com/alexdickson). Then you can write your code like so :

```
$(function () {
    $('#gludeslide').waitForImages(function(){

       var $img = $("#glueslide img");
       ...
       $img.filter(..);
       ..
       $img.eq(index).fadeOut(1000,function(){
       });
```

---

You don't get to control if the browser caches from jQuery, it's based on the headers (an HTTP component coming from the server).

#### [Cache Headers](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires)

Generally the browser will cache images automagically, you just need to wait for the first load.

Comment: thanks but where does the plugin mention anything about caching images. it says it adds handlers to images. What am I missing?

Comment: read the second part of my answer. You don't get to control how the browser caches from jQuery. Its based on the headers.

Comment: I just updated the link with a better article me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is, the way you have written your code you don't need to.

From the look of it you are creating a jquery image rotator. I am assuming your images are there in the HTML and you are using CSS to hide them. The images are downloaded, therefore preloaded and cached as the page loads, before javascript gets involved.

YOu can confirm this by using a tool like Firebug for Firefox (Net Tab) or Developer Tools For Chrome (Network Tab). This will show the images loaded before as part of the document load.